# Nodejs v6: exec "closure compiler" stdout always empty

Tags: node.js

I try to exec CC from nodejs:

```
// already tried exec, spawn
process.execFile('java', [
        '-jar', 'CC-path', '-js', 'js-path', 'other-options'
    ],
    (error, stdout) => {
        if (error != null) {
            throw error    // if there is any errors then will showed in terminal
        }
        console.log(stdout.toString())    // but stdout always empty when no errors exist
    }
)
// I have tested by manual running the command in terminal and got output:
// "...many lines before"
// 0 error(s), 10 warning(s), 74.2% typed
```

How can I get all "Nodejs exec" output like when I manual type the command in terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.execFile()` takes a callback that gets three parameters `(err, stdout, stderr)`.  You should log all three to see what is going on.  My guess is that there is something showing on `stderr` which you are ignoring.  You also aren't logging `err` if there's something there.

```
process.execFile('java', [
        '-jar', 'CC-path', '-js', 'js-path', 'other-options'
    ], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
        console.log("stdout: ", stdout);
        console.log("stderr: ", stderr);
    }
```

Also, your `throw error` will likely do nothing useful because doing a `throw` from within a regular async callback just throws into the bowels of the child_process library, not any where that you can ever catch it.

Comment: hi @jfriend00! I have just tried, "stderr" is also empty.

Comment: So, you're telling me that all three parameters are empty?  I don't know what command line you're trying to run, but where's the actual JAR file you're trying to run?  That sounds like the Java interpreter runs and has nothing to do and thus just exits.  It could also be that you're exceeding `maxBuffer` which just kills the process.

Comment: If errors exist then it will showed, but when no errors then no output. Java just runs fine and my js file was minified correctly but there are 10 warnings and Nodjs exec's stdout got empty.

Comment: Hey, sorry, I have some typing mistake, stderr got the output now. Thank you very much for the advice :D